# ffmpeg concat filter is dropping first second of second video

Tags: ffmpeg, terminal

`con.txt`

```
file one.mp4
file two.mp4
```

The command

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i con.txt out.mp4
```

produces a video that doesn't contain the first second of `two.mp4`.

`ffprobe two.mp4`

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'two.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
  Duration: 00:00:15.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1644 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 428x640, 1644 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10240 tbn, 20 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

I get an interesting error attempting another concatenation method (neither video has audio btw)

`ffmpeg -i one.mp4 -i two.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] [1:v] concat=n=2:v=1:a=0 [v]" -map "[v]" out.mp4`

> Input link in0:v0 parameters (size 428x640, SAR 0:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (428x640, SAR 1576:1575)

How can I join these two videos together sequentially without losing any frames from either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `concat` filter expects the streams to be concatenated to have the identical properties (size, sample aspect ratio (SAR), pix_fmt, etc.). The error message is saying that SARs are not matching up. You can insert `setsar` filters upstream of `concat` filter to resolve this. Assuming these videos have square pixels (1576:1575 is pretty darn close to 1:1), we can do this:

```
ffmpeg -i one.mp4 -i two.mp4 \
  -filter_complex "[0:v]setsar=1:1[L0]; \
                   [1:v]setsar=1:1,fps=30[L1]; \
                   [L0][L1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0 [v] " \
  -map "[v]" out.mp4
```

If you get other errors, you need to prepend more filters to condition your streams to match each other.

Edit: Added `fps` filter to the second video (10 fps) to match the first (30 fps)

Comment: This one prints "More than 1000 frames duplicated" and the time of processing never progresses

Comment: Could you post the full FFmpeg log on your post?

Comment: Here you go: https://pastebin.com/D9iP2uj1 This line might be suspicious "Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it"

Comment: yeah, the input frame rates are not matched either. Use `fps` filter to make them match. I edited my answer to up the second stream to 30 fps from the original 10 fps. If you'd like to change the first stream, add `fps` filter in a similar fashion

Comment: Thank you. Finally I have output, but for some reason they're the wrong way round.

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong way round"? See if the edited answer corrects your issue.

Comment: Yeah, after getting rid of that trailing semicolon it worked this time. By "wrong way round" it meant two.mp4 appeared first, and one.mp4 second.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Fixed the final error